# Input Element Causing Errors

Tags: class, visual-c++, input, compiler-errors

My class is currently studying Classes and I'm attempting to complete my assignment due tomorrow.  I have most of it done, however, for some reason the address input won't let me input any letters only numbers.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here and would appreciate help in figuring out if I need to change something.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class personalData
{
private:
    string name;
    string address;
    int age;
    string phNumber;

public:

    void setName()
    {
        cout << "Enter name: ";
        cin >> name;
    }

    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    void setAddress()
    {
        cout << "Enter address: ";
        cin >> address;
    }

    string getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }

    void setAge()
    {
        cout << "Enter age: ";
        cin >> age;
    }

    int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    void setPhone()
    {
        cout << "Enter phone number: ";
        cin >> phNumber;
    }

    string getPhone()
    {
        return phNumber;
    }

    void displayData()
    {
        cout << "\nName: " << getName() << endl;
        cout << "Address " << getAddress() << endl;
        cout << "Age: " << getAge() << endl;
        cout << "Phone: " << getPhone() << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    personalData person1;
    personalData person3;
    personalData person2;

    person1.setName();
    person1.setAddress();
    person1.setAge();
    person1.setPhone();
    person1.getAddress();

    cout << "\n";

    person2.setName();
    person2.setAddress();
    person2.setAge();
    person2.setPhone();
    person2.getAddress();

    cout << "\n";

    person3.setName();
    person3.setAddress();
    person3.setAge();
    person3.setPhone();
    person3.getAddress();

    cout << "\n";

    cout << "Person1 details: ";
    person1.displayData();

    cout << "Person2 details: ";
    person2.displayData();

    cout << "Person3 details: ";
    person3.displayData();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is what it looks like if you input both numbers and letters:
[image: Image of error occuring]

And here is what happens if you only input numbers:
[image: No Error image]

Comment: `cin >> address` stops reading at the first whitespace character. When you enter *"2020 Last house on the left"*, only "2020` ends up in `address`. Then `setAge()` tries to read "Last" and of course fails. Read about `std::getline` in your favorite C++ textbook and/or lecture notes.

Comment: Everytime I attempt to use a std::getline I get a C3867 error and don't know how I'm supposed to rectify it.

Comment: Well, you must be using it incorrectly. There's a problem somewhere in the code you haven't shown.